# Datetime picker skips items when selecting year month or day Android

Tags: android, datetimepicker

When the simulator runs, the DatetimePicker appears, but when selecting an item it skips several items and gives a value which i didn't select.

eg: when it appears, it shows "Aug 13 1990"  and on top of "aug" its "july". But when i select "july" it spins and get me "January"

Is it something wrong with my emulator specs? or the code? 
Or is there another way to do this date selection?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {                  
       @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_birthday);
            editText.setText(year + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        }
    },1990, 9, 13);
    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");                
    mDatePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
// initialise your datePicker

Dialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year,
                month, day);
        datedial.show();
```

// and here is your datePickerListener

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        date = selectedYear + "-" + (selectedMonth + 1) + "-" + selectedDay;

     // format your date in desired format

        SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
        try {
            Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd MMMM yyyy");
            String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
            yourEditText.setText(newDateStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, the above method also didnt work. but then i changed my simulator to a device with a higher resolution and then it worked properly. That means my app wont work in devices with smaller resolutions? :/

Comment: Hi, Sorry for causing trouble. Now i just installed the file in my phone and it works perfectly. Must be an issue with the device simulator i was working on before :/